# 'Login Required' error. How to login after getting oauth2 token with Google API

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-analytics-api

I'm building a small Node/React app where I'm trying to implement OAuth2 Google to request the Google Analytics API. I'm using [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) to handle the authentification.

I'm able to get the Token correctly:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect("http://localhost:5000/?token=" + token);
    }
);
```

However, when trying to call the Google Analytics management API I have the following error `Error: Login Required`.

```
router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    googleAccounts.management.profiles.list(
      {
        accountId: '~all',
        webPropertyId: '~all'
      },
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error: ' + err)
          res.send('An error occurred')
        } else if (data) {

          Console.log(data)

        }
      }
    )
})
```

How do I login? What step I'm missing?

Comment: Do you login to Google when you generate the token?

Comment: yes I have a sign in button on the client-side redirecting to this address "http://localhost:5000/auth/google". then I have the typical Google Login window.

Comment: Did you request correct scope(s)? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren’t sending the access token, unless you’re using the gapi’s inbuilt auth, you have to send the access token manually in a HTTP authorization header.

Please use the following snippet to achieve the same.

```
function listViews() {
  gapi.client.setToken({
    access_token: <access-token>
  })
  ... rest of the function
```