# How to make the Google oAuth2Client object reusable Node.js app-wide?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am building a Node.js CLI that does Google Drive API and Docs API calls that are predefined in functions.
But because every API call has to be authorized, I created a separate file and function that reads the credentials and should return the authorized `oAuth2Client` object to be exported and reused in any function where it needs to be passed as a parameter.
The idea is that a `readCredentials()` function call will call the `authorize()` function, which should return the `oAuth2Client` object if there is a `token.json` present. Otherwise it will prompt the user for authentication with the `getAccessToken()` function.
The whole logic is actually just slightly modified from the [quickstart example in the Google Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs), but intended to be reusable in any function in the app, not just in the current file.
But for some reason I get `GaxiosError: Login Required` returned in the console when I try to call and store the credentials in a variable, and then use them to authorize an API call in my `index.js`.
Does anybody have a clue what is going wrong?

**authorize.js**

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"];

const TOKEN_PATH = "token.json";

const readCredentials = () => {
  fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
    authorize(JSON.parse(content));
  });
};

const authorize = (credentials) => {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
  });

  return oAuth2Client;
};

const getAccessToken = (oAuth2Client) => {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);

      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
      });

      return oAuth2Client;
    });
  });
};

module.exports = { readCredentials };
```

**index.js**

```js
const authorize = require("./authorize");
const drive = require("./drive");
...
let credentials = authorize.readCredentials();

drive.createFolder(credentials);
...
```

Comment: Its not an issue with scope right? your not mixing calls to different endpoints that require different scopes then the one you are showing here.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58018756/11551468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Node.js, you can start out with using passport.js. It will store the user information in a session, and can be accessed with `req.user`. To use the API, you will need `access_token` of the user, which you can obtain with a `refresh_token`. Here is a basic example from passport.js' website.

```js
var GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://yourdomain:3000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));


app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope:
      [ 'email', 'profile' ] }
));

app.get( '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/google/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure'
}));
```

I would suggest adding the `refresh_token` to the database as well, so you can get an `access_token` anytime. In the example above, it is using the Mongo Database.